# Difficulty in using sed command in ssh session in shell script in solaris

Tags: ssh

I am trying to do something like this inside ssh session:

Script

```
ssh remoteservername "
col=`sed -n "8p" /tmp/temp.txt`
echo $col>>/tmp/Ankur.txt
"
```

This is not working and it is printing empty line instead of text what I want to store in col variable, why so, and this is working:

```
ssh remoteservername "
sed -n "8p" /tmp/temp.txt>>/tmp/Ankur.txt
"
```

This Ankur.txt file is on the remote server....The main focus is how to get the output of the command inside a variable so that i can use it further.

Please tell how to make it work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use double quotes the variable names will get expanded before passing them, so `$col` is getting expanded locally before running on the remote server.  You can either escape the `$` like `\$col` or use single quotes around it, which is probably better since you want to use double quotes inside the command as well

```
ssh remoteservername '
col=`sed -n "8p" /tmp/temp.txt`
echo $col>>/tmp/Ankur.txt
'
```

Without changing the quotes

```
ssh remoteservername 'sed -n "8p" /tmp/temp.txt >> /tmp/Ankur.txt'
```

as you noted, still works, by redirecting the output directly into the file.  This avoids the variable expansion problem from the double quotes above.

If you're going to have many steps though, you might want to just create a script on `remoteservername` and invoke that in your `ssh` command rather than doing a lot on the same command line.

Comment: Thanks Eric for pointing out the single quote usage..it worked..Thanks

Comment: I'm glad to help. If that answer worked for you, you can accept the answer so the question will show up as answered

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **local file** to execute complex commands and to use variables in remote machine via SSH as shown below.

> **1. Create a input file 'input_file.txt'**
>
> ```
> #-- input_file.txt
> col=`sed -n "8p" /tmp/temp.txt`
> echo $col>>/tmp/Ankur.txt
> ```
>
> **2. Execute the commands of input file in remote server via SSH**
>
> `ssh remoteservername "sh -s" < input_file.txt`